# collision edges of the component and forms in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a simple arcanoid. misrepresented the problem that I can not catch the moment when the left edge of the button to the left crane hits the screen.

```
private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)          
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.A)
    {
        if (ActiveForm.Left - button1.Left<10)
        {
            button1.Left -= 10;
        }

    }
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.D)
    {
         button1.Left += 10;
    }                
}
```

Comment: In your current code, it doesn't seem like you have even attempted to catch that moment - at least without doing anything fancy, the left edge of the screen (well, parent control) has X coordinates *0*, so you should just compare your `button1.Left` to that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your if for the button1.left code.

I suppose that the ActiveForm is the form showing the game itself, and you want to move your bar to the left until it hits the left side of ActiveForm.

Take a look at this picture, basically the Form.Left is the distance between the left side of your screen and the form itself:

[image]

Instead of checking the bar position with the Form.Left, check it against "0 - bar.width", the left side of your form is always 0, so you can move the bar to the left as far as it's value is bigger than the width of the bar (bigger than 10 I presume).

Comment: not quite right and does not work. I will have the same ball ich should start from the edges of the form. These coordinates also need to compare. I also compared only with respect to the screen itself.